# java.net.SocketException: Permission denied in Android Studio with Visual Studio 2017 Web Service

Tags: java, android, visual-studio-2017

I use KSOAP2 library in Android Studio, SQL SERVER with an "Clientes" table and web service ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2017.

When I call a Web Service SOAP "TareaWSConsulta" and "TareaWSEnviar" it returns me this exceptions:

```
11-05 07:14:56.592 12155-12248/com.example.ruper.serviciosweb_soap_rest E/CONSULTA: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
11-05 07:15:10.878 12155-12172/com.example.ruper.serviciosweb_soap_rest E/ENVIAR: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
```

I don't know what is the problem. VISUAL STUDIO is open an running correctly and I request the INTERNET permission and I have the same problem... Help me please! Thanks!

AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ruper.serviciosweb_soap_rest">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My MainActivity class:

```
package com.example.ruper.serviciosweb_soap_rest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etxtNombre, etxtTelefono;
    Button btnEnviar, btnConsultar;
    ListView lstClientes;
    TextView tviewResultado;


String NAMESPACE="ruperdevcoder";
String URL="http://10.0.2.2:51629/ServicioClientes.asmx";
String METHOD_NAME="NuevoClienteSimple";
String SOAP_ACTION="ruperdevcoder/NuevoClienteSimple";

private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etxtNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtNombre);
    etxtTelefono = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtTelefono);
    btnEnviar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
    btnConsultar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConsultar);
    tviewResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tviewResultado);
    lstClientes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstClientes);
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
    if(permissionCheck!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)){
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            },MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET);
        }
    }

    btnConsultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TareaWSConsulta tarea = new TareaWSConsulta();
            tarea.execute();
        }
    });

    btnEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TareaWSEnviar tarea = new TareaWSEnviar();
            tarea.execute(etxtNombre.getText().toString(),etxtTelefono.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[],int[]grantResults){
    switch(requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET:{
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            }else{
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}

private class TareaWSConsulta extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {

    private Cliente[] listaClientes;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Boolean result=true;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


        try{
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject resSoap=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            listaClientes = new Cliente[resSoap.getPropertyCount()];

            for(int i=0; i<listaClientes.length;i++){
                SoapObject ic = (SoapObject) resSoap.getProperty(i);

                Cliente cli = new Cliente();
                cli.id=Integer.parseInt(ic.getProperty(0).toString());
                cli.nombre=ic.getProperty(1).toString();
                cli.telefono=Integer.parseInt(ic.getProperty(2).toString());
                listaClientes[i]=cli;
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("CONSULTA", e.toString());
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        if(result){
            final String[] datos = new String[listaClientes.length];
            for(int i=0;i<listaClientes.length;i++){

                datos[i]=listaClientes[i].nombre;
                ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);

                lstClientes.setAdapter(adaptador);
            }
        }else{
            tviewResultado.setText("Error!");
        }
    }
}
private class TareaWSEnviar extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean>{
    public TareaWSEnviar() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result=true;

        String nombre= params[0];
        String telefono= params[1];

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("nombre", nombre);
        request.addProperty("telefono", telefono);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultado_xml= (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String res=resultado_xml.toString();
            if(!res.equals(1)){
                result=false;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ENVIAR",e.toString());
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result){
            tviewResultado.setText("INSERTADO OK!");
        }else{
            tviewResultado.setText("ERROR!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Add permission Internet, <uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: You added it at the wrong place. Put it above the `<application` tag.

Comment: Ups.... Thanks! jaja, Now I have the next error when execute "TareaWSConsulta": java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 400. The NAMESPACE, URL, METHOD_NAME and SOAP_ACTION are correct... Any idea what the problem should be?

Answer (score 0):

Try using https in your url, not http.

For your url, change:

String URL="http://10.0.2.2:51629/ServicioClientes.asmx";

to:

String URL="https://10.0.2.2:51629/ServicioClientes.asmx";

Hope this helps, as it worked for me.