# java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 400 in ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, sql-server, visual-studio, soap

This is a continuation of this link:

[java.net.SocketException: Permission denied in Android Studio with Visual Studio 2017 Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119412/java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-in-android-studio-with-visual-studio)

I use KSOAP2 library in Android Studio, SQL SERVER with an "Clientes" table and web service ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2017.

AndroidManifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ruper.serviciosweb_soap_rest">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My MainActivity class:

```
package com.example.ruper.serviciosweb_soap_rest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etxtNombre, etxtTelefono;
    Button btnEnviar, btnConsultar;
    ListView lstClientes;
    TextView tviewResultado;


String NAMESPACE="ruperdevcoder";
String URL="http://10.0.2.2:51629/ServicioClientes.asmx";
String METHOD_NAME="NuevoClienteSimple";
String SOAP_ACTION="ruperdevcoder/NuevoClienteSimple";

private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET=1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etxtNombre = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtNombre);
    etxtTelefono = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etxtTelefono);
    btnEnviar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnviar);
    btnConsultar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnConsultar);
    tviewResultado = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tviewResultado);
    lstClientes = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstClientes);
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
    if(permissionCheck!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)){
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            },MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET);
        }
    }

    btnConsultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TareaWSConsulta tarea = new TareaWSConsulta();
            tarea.execute();
        }
    });

    btnEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TareaWSEnviar tarea = new TareaWSEnviar();
            tarea.execute(etxtNombre.getText().toString(),etxtTelefono.getText().toString());
        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[],int[]grantResults){
    switch(requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET:{
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            }else{
            }
            return;
        }

    }
}

private class TareaWSConsulta extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean> {

    private Cliente[] listaClientes;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        Boolean result=true;

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


        try{
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            SoapObject resSoap=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            listaClientes = new Cliente[resSoap.getPropertyCount()];

            for(int i=0; i<listaClientes.length;i++){
                SoapObject ic = (SoapObject) resSoap.getProperty(i);

                Cliente cli = new Cliente();
                cli.id=Integer.parseInt(ic.getProperty(0).toString());
                cli.nombre=ic.getProperty(1).toString();
                cli.telefono=Integer.parseInt(ic.getProperty(2).toString());
                listaClientes[i]=cli;
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e("CONSULTA", e.toString());
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        if(result){
            final String[] datos = new String[listaClientes.length];
            for(int i=0;i<listaClientes.length;i++){

                datos[i]=listaClientes[i].nombre;
                ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);

                lstClientes.setAdapter(adaptador);
            }
        }else{
            tviewResultado.setText("Error!");
        }
    }
}
private class TareaWSEnviar extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean>{
    public TareaWSEnviar() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        boolean result=true;

        String nombre= params[0];
        String telefono= params[1];

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        request.addProperty("nombre", nombre);
        request.addProperty("telefono", telefono);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{
            transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultado_xml= (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            String res=resultado_xml.toString();
            if(!res.equals(1)){
                result=false;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("ENVIAR",e.toString());
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(result){
            tviewResultado.setText("INSERTADO OK!");
        }else{
            tviewResultado.setText("ERROR!");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have the next error when execute "TareaWSConsulta":

```
java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 400
```

The NAMESPACE, URL, METHOD_NAME and SOAP_ACTION are correct... Any idea what the problem should be? Thanks!

Comment: The fact you got a 400 means the server got the request and responded.  However it didn't understand the request.  Why it would return that is totally dependent on the server's code for that endpoint.  You may be sending up a bad combo of values, or missing a value.  But without knowing your server's code, we can't say what happened.  If your server has decent logging you may have a better error message there

Comment: I use VS 2017. In the logging does not indicate anything. It can be an authentication / security issue?

Comment: You aren't using VS2017 as a server, that's an IDE.  It could be an authentication issue, if the server decided to return that rather than 403.

Comment: You're right! I am using IIS Express that is installed automatically with VS2017. I have not configured anything from IIS Express since the Android Studio emulator is on the same pc.

Answer (score 0):

```
transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);// error here 
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/UpdateNotificationToken" // soap action like that and you using 
 String SOAP_ACTION="ruperdevcoder/NuevoClienteSimple"; //change this
```

You can get soap action from asmx file

```
    POST /Services/apk_Driver.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: redrive.orataro.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
 SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/UpdateNotificationToken"

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <soap:Body>
        <UpdateNotificationToken xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <DriverID>string</DriverID>
          <CompanyID>string</CompanyID>
          <NotificationToken>string</NotificationToken>
          <DeviceType>string</DeviceType>
        </UpdateNotificationToken>
      </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

My NAMESPACE is "ruperdevcoder" and the SOAPACTION of the WebMethod is "ruperdevcoder/ListadoClientes":

```
POST /ServicioClientes.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "ruperdevcoder/ListadoClientes"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ListadoClientes xmlns="ruperdevcoder" />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ListadoClientesResponse xmlns="ruperdevcoder">
      <ListadoClientesResult>
        <Cliente>
          <Id>int</Id>
          <Nombre>string</Nombre>
          <Telefono>int</Telefono>
        </Cliente>
        <Cliente>
          <Id>int</Id>
          <Nombre>string</Nombre>
          <Telefono>int</Telefono>
        </Cliente>
      </ListadoClientesResult>
    </ListadoClientesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My .asmx.cs file in VisualStudio 2017:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ServicioWebSoap
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "ruperdevcoder")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    public class ServicioClientes : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public int NuevoClienteSimple(string nombre, int telefono) {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (localdb)\ServidorLocal; Initial Catalog=DBCLIENTES;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            string sql = "INSERT INTO Clientes(Nombre, Telefono) VALUES (@nombre, @telefono)";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = nombre;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@telefono", SqlDbType.Int).Value = telefono;

            int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            return res;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public Cliente[] ListadoClientes(){

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\ServidorLocal;Initial Catalog=DBCLIENTES;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT IdCliente, Nombre, Telefono FROM Clientes";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<Cliente> lista = new List<Cliente>();

            while (reader.Read()) {
                lista.Add(new Cliente(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetInt32(2)));
            }
            con.Close();

            return lista.ToArray();
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public int NuevoClienteObjeto(Cliente cliente) {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\ServidorLocal; Initial Catalog=DBCLIENTES;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            string sql = "INSERT INTO Clientes(Nombre, Telefono) VALUES (@nombre,@telefono)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nombre", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cliente.Nombre;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@telefono", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cliente.Telefono;

            int res = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();
            return res;
        }

    }
}
```